# Как сделать суммирование в сводной таблице?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot

Мой код:

```
new6 = new3.groupby(['YrSold', 'Flag'])['SalePrice'].aggregate('sum')
new6
```

Как сделать то же самое, но с помощью new6 = `new3.pivot_table(...`?

Так пыталась, не работает:

```
new6 = new3.pivot_table(values=['YrSold', 'Flag'], index=['SalePrice'], aggfunc='sum')
```

Так должно быть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И как этот столбец, где сумма, именовать, чтоб надпись была над ним была 'Summa'?

Comment: new6.reset_index(name=“Summa”) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем понятно зачем вам PIVOT. Для такой простой задачи `df.groupby().sum()` - более идиоматическое решение.

```
In [10]: new3.groupby(['YrSold', 'Flag'])['SalePrice'].sum().reset_index(name="Summa")
Out[10]:
   YrSold  Flag     Summa
0    2006     0  28193621
1    2006     1  29126909
2    2007     0  30848091
3    2007     1  30366686
4    2008     0  26948329
5    2008     1  26969366
6    2009     0  32986315
7    2009     1  27661736
8    2010     0  14862208
9    2010     1  16181685
```

Если все же нужен PIVOT:

```
In [8]: (new3.pivot_table(index=['YrSold', 'Flag'], values=['SalePrice'], aggfunc='sum')
             .rename(columns={"SalePrice":"Summa"})
             .reset_index()
Out[8]:
   YrSold  Flag     Summa
0    2006     0  28193621
1    2006     1  29126909
2    2007     0  30848091
3    2007     1  30366686
4    2008     0  26948329
5    2008     1  26969366
6    2009     0  32986315
7    2009     1  27661736
8    2010     0  14862208
9    2010     1  16181685
```

Comment: Да, спасибо тоже также уже сама сделала `new8 = new3[mask].pivot_table(values=['SalePrice', 'Flag'], index=['YrSold'], aggfunc='sum')`

Comment: Хотя решение MaxU работает только без reset_index(name="Summa") `res = new3.pivot_table(index=['YrSold', 'Flag'], values=['SalePrice'], aggfunc='sum')`

Comment: @svil, `.reset_index(name="Summa")` отработает правильно если у вас единственный столбец данных и мультииндекс (как показано в вопросе). Можете привести в вопросе или выложить на какой-нибудь файлообменник воспроизводимый пример данных?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=152H-TILAnZJnh6n_K61V4CgR5dICj6sk

Comment: Атрибут Flag добавлен по коду `new3.assign(Flag=pd.Series(np.random.randint(0, 2, new.shape[0])).values)`